# How to package knex in my electron app to use sqlite3

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, knex.js

In my electron app I want to package knex to use an sqlite3 database.

**My package.json file**

```
{
    "name": "p",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "T",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
        "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"PlanGo\"",
        "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
        "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
    },
    "author": "R",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.4",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "knex": "^0.21.6",
        "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron-packager": "^15.1.0",
        "electron-rebuild": "^2.2.0",
        "electron": "^10.1.3"
    }
}
```

I have followed the following tutorial to package my app https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this question myself because I was able to package it

Firstly, I used `"electron-builder": "^22.9.1"`, instead of `electron-packager`.

Next, the reason it wasn't being packaged is because the storage location of my app data wasn't specified properly.

I was using sqlite database and a json file.

On windows you have make sure it gets saved under APP DATA > your foldername.
Electron will handle this automatically if you use

```
jsonPath = path.join(process.env.APPDATA, "/MyFileName/jsonFile.json");
```

This should solve any packaging errors you might face.